# PLSQL fetch does not exit

Tags: oracle, plsql

Have this employee table:
[image]

And a plsql query:

```
DECLARE
    totaal_salaris    INT := 0;
    CURSOR medewerker_cur IS
      SELECT naam, maandsal
      FROM MEDEWERKERS;
      medewerker_row    medewerker_cur%rowtype;
BEGIN  
    OPEN medewerker_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH medewerker_cur INTO medewerker_row;
      EXIT WHEN medewerker_cur%NOTFOUND OR totaal_salaris > 50000;
      UPDATE medewerkers
        SET maandsal = (medewerker_row.maandsal * 1.10)
        WHERE naam = medewerker_row.naam;
      totaal_salaris := totaal_salaris + medewerker_row.maandsal;
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('Totaal uit te keren salaris: ' || totaal_salaris);
END;
/
```

The intention was to increase all existing employees salary (maandsal) by 10% so long as the total salary < 50.000. But this is not working out at all..

I 3 double checked witch running the script and this is the result I get:

**Some test results:**

**First time running:**

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.Totaal uit te keren salaris: 55000

maandsal changed into 5500;

**Second time**

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.Totaal uit te keren salaris: 55000

maandsal changed into 6050

**Thirth time**

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. Totaal uit te keren salaris: 54450

maandsal changed into 6655

Comment: All salaries are increased on each run, or just some of them? Also is your running total supposed to be of the old or new salaries? And your cursor query is unordered so which employees get raises is indeterminate (the real world fells like that sometimes...); and look into `for update`.

Comment: Sorry for my uncertainty. The test results I get from all employees salary increase. Already tried a lot. But can't figure it out. I thing my whole query is wrong

Comment: The 'total' line doesn't agree; if it wasn't exiting the loop that would be much higher, each time.

Comment: Okeoke, You mean the OR totaal_salaris > 50000 isn't called or totaal_salaris := totaal_salaris + medewerker_row.maandsal does not work?:o

Comment: No, they do appear to work. You're exiting the loop after 11 iterations the first time, 10 iterations the second time, and 9 the third time, as it hits >50000 sooner. (Add debugs to verify that). If it wasn't doing that you'd see 70000 the first time (14x5000), not 55000. If I create your data and run your code I see 11 set to 5500 and 2 left as 5000. After three iterations I have 10x6655, 1x6050, 1x5500 and 2x5000. If you are seeing **all** rows as 6655 then you are not running the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the solution.

```
DECLARE
    total_salaris    INT := 0;

    CURSOR employee_cur IS
      SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary
      FROM employees;

    employee_rec   employee_cur%rowtype;

BEGIN  
    OPEN employee_cur;
    LOOP
      FETCH employee_cur INTO employee_rec;
      total_salaris := total_salaris + (employee_rec.salary * 1.1);
      EXIT WHEN employee_cur%NOTFOUND OR total_salaris > 50000;

      UPDATE employees
        SET salary = (employee_rec.salary * 1.10)
        WHERE employee_id = employee_rec.employee_id;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE employee_cur;

END;
```